# Convert link markers to links

Tags: javascript, regex

I have text that contains certain markers, where I want to replace links according to this scheme: `...[DESCRIPTION][URL]...` should become `...<a href="URL">DESCRIPTION</a>...`

```
var string = 'Lorem ipsum [dolor][http://example.com/one] sit amet. Lorem ipsum [dolor][http://example.com/two] sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor [sit amet][http://example.com/three].'
```

Should become

```
var string = 'Lorem ipsum <a href="http://example.com/one">dolor</a> sit amet. Lorem ipsum <a href="http://example.com/two">dolor</a> sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor <a href="http://example.com/three">sit amet</a>.'
```

How can I use Javascript to achieve this?

Comment: When you attempted to solve this problem yourself - before asking this question - how far did you get? Where did you get stuck? What went wrong? What error(s) came from those attempts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use RegEx to replace all the occurances of [text1][text2].

`string.replace(/\[(.*?)\]\[(.*?)\]/, '<a href="$2">$1</a>');`

`(.*?)` accounts for any and all letters from the first `[` to the last `]` within that same range. The `g` in the end accounts for all occurances in the same string.